# Zend\Form and REST: Make Zend\Form accept partial data to implement a HTTP PATCH method

Tags: php, forms, rest, zend-framework

We are implementing a REST API using `Zend\Form`. This is working fine for the HTTP methods `PUT` and `POST`. Both types of request contain a complete representation of the object's data so its a no-brainer to use `Zend\Form` to validate it. We simply set the received data on the form instance and done.

However, `PATCH` requests only contain partial data: the data that is supposed to be changed and nothing else. Simply setting the received data on the form results in failed validation, because obviously some data is missing.

Can you make `Zend\Form` accept partial data somehow? Is this what the 'allow_empty' `InputFilter` options are there for? Or do we have to fetch the existing data and merge it with the received data manually before setting the data on the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently `Zend\Form` is not supposed to support partial data. So in order to use `Zend\Form` for a `PATCH` request, the only solution was fetching the full object from the database and then merging the request's data into the fetched data.